# Retrieving a JSON feed of my posts and displaying thumbnails

Tags: json

I want to show a feed of my latest posts though json.

I seem to be able to do it - up to a point. I am retrieving my feed like so:

```
var json = <?php echo json_encode($query->get_posts()); ?>;
```

Problem is, I can't retrieve the post thumbnails, I can just retreive the post title and a bunch of other information, but can't seem to get what I'm looking for. Any idea how I can do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$posts = $query->get_posts();

foreach($posts as $p){

    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($p->ID);
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'image_size');

    $url = $src ? $src[0] : false;

    $p->image_url = $url;
}

$json = json_encode($posts);
```

Now you can echo out `$json` into your JS var. You will find the image url string in the key `image_url` of your json object. You can test if there is an image by testing if the value returned is false or not.

Be sure to change `image_size` in the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` function to the name of the image size you want.

In essence we are looping over the query, grabbing the post thumbnail and finding the url of the image we want, then we add it to the object as a new property.

Any questions, just ask.